# Merge two mysql table from 2 supplier same product but different ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on project for retail business but have some issue about MySql data.
We have 2 table from 2 suppliers. 
Some product they use same name different ID but some aren't. Some product only supplier A can offer.

```
Supplier A
ProductID  productName
A1         Product 1
A2         Product 2


Supplier B
ProductID  productName
B1         Product 1
B2         Product 2.0
B3         Product 3

I want to create new table with our own Product id to use it as primary product data.

Products table
ProductID, A,    B,  productName 
P1          A1    B1   Product 1              
P2          A2    null Product 2
P3          null  B2   Product 2.0
P4          null  B3   Product 3
```

Thank you.

Comment: What have you try so far? It's a pretty straigth forward SQL query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest three tables.  The first would be a `Products` table, with a name chosen from either supplier who provides the product.  The second would be a `Suppliers` table, with information about the suppliers.  And the third would be `ProductSuppliers` with one row per supplier and products.  Sample data would be:

```
create table Products (
    ProductId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ProductName
);

create table Suppliers (
    SupplierId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    SupplierName
);

create table ProductSuppliers (
    ProductSuppliersId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    ProductId int not null references Products(ProductId),
    SupplierId int not null references Suppliers(SupplierId),
    SupplierProductCode varchar(255)
);
```

You can then populate these from your table:

```
insert into Products(ProductName)
    select ProductName
    from SupplierA
    union
    select ProductName
    from SupplierB;

insert into Suppliers(SupplierName)
    select 'A' union all select 'B';


insert into SupplierProducts(SupplierId, ProductId, SupplierProductCode)
    select s.SupplierId, p.ProductId, a.ProductCode
    from SupplierA a join
         Products p
         on a.ProductName = p.ProductName cross join
         (select SupplierId from Suppliers where SupplierName = 'A') s;

insert into SupplierProducts(SupplierId, ProductId, SupplierProductCode)
    select s.SupplierId, p.ProductId, b.ProductCode
    from SupplierB b join
         Products p
         on b.ProductName = p.ProductName cross join
         (select SupplierId from Suppliers where SupplierName = 'B') s;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it.
But some product actually it is the same but supplier spell name different. Is any way can compare similar name and put in one row?

Comment: @Boyz . . . That is exactly why you want your own name for the product.  You can have another column, something like `ProductName` in the SupplierProducts` table.  You will have to make some effort to disentangle your data, though.